# How to fetch all specific PRODUCT_NAME that has 200 - 50 QUANTITY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I'm beginner developer, I'm making right now a table that need to be filled by products that have 200 to 50 quantity left.

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY (QUANTITY) WHERE QUANTITY = '200-50' DESC limit  $start_from,$num_per_page";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
```

Hi I'm here again, I follow the instruction about WHERE and ORDER BY, but there is a error too. what is he error of this code?

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (QUANTITY) >='50' and (QUANTITY) <='200' $start_from,$num_per_page";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
```

I want to fetch all products that have a 200-50 quantity

Comment: `where quantity >=50 and quantity <=200` or `where quantity between 50 and 200`? assuming that you are talking about a range of values rather than 200 minus 50

Comment: `order by` goes after `where`. Check the syntax for `order by`

Comment: Is that wrong brombeer?

Comment: Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.htmlfor correct syntax

Comment: "SELECT * FROM products WHERE ORDER BY (QUANTITY) >='50' and quantity <='200'"
I follow your instruction but there is error "Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception:"

Comment: In your added code you are missing a `LIMIT` before `$start_from,$num_per_page`. Use proper error reporting to see any errors/warnings  returned

Comment: Try this : $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE QUANTITY >= 50 and QUANTITY <= 200 ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC LIMIT $start_from, $num_per_page";

Comment: I think you understood `order by goes after where` a bit too literally. Please...take a basic SQL course if you don't understand the purpose and usage of these keywords, as this is fairly entry-level stuff. Another point...numbers are not text. If you expect SQL to treat them as numbers, don't put them inside quote marks.